# Datatable Server Side não faz paginação, ordenação nem pesquisa

Tags: php, datatable

beleza? Então, estou passando o processamento da minha datatable para serverside, devido a lentidão extrema com alto volume de dados. Os dados estão sendo retornados via json encode perfeitamente, porém, a paginação, ordenação e a pesquisa da datatable não estão funcionando. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue códigos abaixo.

Código Html + Jquery

```
<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id Empresa</th>
      <th>Cidade</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "table_server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Código PHP da página table_server_processing.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP 5.2+ and MySQL 4.1+
* Notes:     Based on a script by Allan Jardine that used the old PHP mysql_* functions.
*            Rewritten to use the newer object oriented mysqli extension.
* Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine (original script)
*            2012 - Kari Söderholm, aka Haprog (updates)
* License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
*/

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

/**
 * Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */

$aColumns = array( 'id_empresa', 'cidade', 'estado' );

// Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality)

$sIndexColumn = "id_empresa";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "cadastro_fornec";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql ['user'] = "connect@cubo";
$gaSql ['password'] = "4c3sso4lm0xcub0c0nn3ct";
$gaSql ['db'] = "voucher";
$gaSql ['server'] = "192.168.20.16";

// Input method (use $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST)

$input =& $_GET;

/** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/**
 * Character set to use for the MySQL connection.
 * MySQL will return all strings in this charset to PHP (if the data is stored correctly in the database).
 */
$gaSql['charset']  = 'utf8';

/**
 * MySQL connection
 */

$db = new mysqli($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password'], $gaSql['db']);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die( 'Error connecting to MySQL server (' . mysqli_connect_errno() .') '. mysqli_connect_error() );
}

if (!$db->set_charset($gaSql['charset'])) {
    die( 'Error loading character set "'.$gaSql['charset'].'": '.$db->error );
}


/**
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $input['iDisplayStart'] ) && $input['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
    $sLimit = " LIMIT ".intval( $input['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $input['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/**
 * Ordering
 */
$aOrderingRules = array();
if ( isset( $input['iSortCol_0'] ) ) {
    $iSortingCols = intval( $input['iSortingCols'] );
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iSortingCols ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $input[ 'bSortable_'.intval($input['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == 'true' ) {
            $aOrderingRules[] =
            "`".$aColumns[ intval( $input['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` "
                    .($input['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($aOrderingRules)) {
    $sOrder = " ORDER BY ".implode(", ", $aOrderingRules);
} else {
    $sOrder = "";
}


/**
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$iColumnCount = count($aColumns);

if ( isset($input['sSearch']) && $input['sSearch'] != "" ) {
    $aFilteringRules = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($input['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true' ) {
            $aFilteringRules[] = "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string( $input['sSearch'] )."%'";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($aFilteringRules)) {
        $aFilteringRules = array('('.implode(" OR ", $aFilteringRules).')');
    }
}

// Individual column filtering

for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
    if ( isset($input['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true' && $input['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
        $aFilteringRules[] = "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string($input['sSearch_'.$i])."%'";
    }
}

if (!empty($aFilteringRules)) {
    $sWhere = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $aFilteringRules);
} else {
    $sWhere = "";
}

/**
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$aQueryColumns = array();
foreach ($aColumns as $col) {
    if ($col != ' ') {
        $aQueryColumns[] = $col;
    }
}

$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace ( " , ", " ", implode ( ", ", $aColumns ) ) . "
    FROM `".$sTable;

$rResult = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);

// Data set length after filtering

$sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$rResultFilterTotal = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);
list($iFilteredTotal) = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_row();

// Total data set length

$sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`) FROM `".$sTable."`";
$rResultTotal = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);
list($iTotal) = $rResultTotal->fetch_row();


/**
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
        "sEcho"                => intval($input['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords"        => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData"               => array(),
);

while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == 'version' ) {
            // Special output formatting for 'version' column
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=='0') ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        } elseif ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' ) {
            // General output
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Já viste os exemplos deles? Não estás a conseguir adaptar?https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html,https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: Este exemplo que estou usando retirei da documentação do Datatable. Ele só não está fazendo a ordenação, paginação e pesquisa, mas o retorno dos dados está funcionando ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar na sua query principal as partes do SQL que o script monta e que vão efetivamente fazer suas devidas funções, algo como:

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace ( " , ", " ", implode ( ", ", $aColumns ) ) . "
    FROM `".$sTable . $sWhere . $sOrder . $sLimit;
```

Comment: Jader, primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda. Essas partes seria o que? Não entendi muito bem...

Comment: @TiagoMartins elas complementam a consulta com a busca, ordem e paginação, procure as variáveis $sWhere, $sOrder e $sLimit no código e veja como elas são definidas para entender melhor...

Comment: consegui resolver seguindo sua dica, valeu! A minha variável `$sQuery` funcionou da seguinte maneira.                  

`$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
FROM $sTable
$sWhere
$sOrder
$sLimit";`